# JBoss AS 7 read remote JMS queue

Tags: jboss, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I have two servers:

- server A, with jms queue implemented with jboss as7.1.1 final
- server B, JBoss AS 7.1.1 where I would setup a connection to server A for use the JMS queue.

I've the servers on same machine but running on different port , i've changend all port to avoid conflict.

i've tried to follow these [instructions](http://lukaszantoniak.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/jboss-as-7-remote-jms-queue/)
and:
The first server run as well, but the second server gives an error that missing dependencies for ConnectionFactory1Mgmt.

i've made an mdb on server B that references ConnectionFactory1NonMgmt.

I readed from official documentation that i can call remote queue from server B by using jms-bridge

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Messaging+configuration

what's the best approaches?

Comment: What's mdv? MDB? Please give the question some culture, this is not java ranch. Good question increases chance to get an answer.

Comment: I was succesfully using Lukasz Antoniak's instructions with similiar architecture. Actually resigned from it as it did't work well in case of clustered HornetQ servers and I never liked that on client I setup connection factories inside messaging subsystem which is actually starting embeded Hornetq. Jboss will say this ok, but I had a situation when have to add some unwanted HornetQ directories settings to make it working. We switched to use org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQXAConnectionFactory factories build on org.hornetq.api.core.DiscoveryGroupConfiguration. As Ondra said give  more details.

Comment: i've resolved, the missing configuration is : add  <mdb> <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="remote-jms-mgmt"/> <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/> </mdb><br/> inside <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.4">

Comment: @antoniog... Post your solution as Update in the `Question`? So, It's useful for future references.

Comment: or rather as an answer.